# Is it possible to get FFmpeg to use hardware acceleration for HEVC transcoding on macOS?

Tags: macos, ffmpeg, h.265

I have a MacBook Pro with a Kaby Lake processor running macOS High Sierra (10.12). Is it possibe somehow to setup FFmpeg to utilize hardware encoding of HEVC with toolbox, instead of libx265?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On MacOSX there’s Videotoolbox,  a low-level framework that provides direct access to hardware encoders and decoders. It provides services for video compression and decompression, and for conversion between raster image formats stored in [CoreVideo](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corevideo) pixel buffers. These services are provided in the form of session objects (compression, decompression, and pixel transfer), which are vended as [Core Foundation (CF) types](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/working-with-core-foundation-types).

FFmpeg implements Videotoolbox in both hardware contexts (for H/W acceleration bring-up) and as encoder wrappers (for transcoding supported codecs).

Check out the private encoder options for `hevc_videotoolbox` encoder wrapper:

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -h encoder=hevc_videotoolbox
```

**Output:**

```
Supported pixel formats: videotoolbox_vld nv12 yuv420p
hevc_videotoolbox AVOptions:
  -profile           <int>        E..V.... Profile (from 0 to 3) (default 0)
     main                         E..V.... Main Profile
     main10                       E..V.... Main10 Profile
  -allow_sw          <boolean>    E..V.... Allow software encoding (default false)
  -realtime          <boolean>    E..V.... Hint that encoding should happen in real-time if not faster (e.g. capturing from camera). (default false)
  -frames_before     <boolean>    E..V.... Other frames will come before the frames in this session. This helps smooth concatenation issues. (default false)
  -frames_after      <boolean>    E..V.... Other frames will come after the frames in this session. This helps smooth concatenation issues. (default false)
```

Note that the output may change over time as more features are exposed in more recent ffmpeg builds.

Maybe you can test with that, if you have a recent Mac.

As you can see, it taps into the hardware-based encoders available on macOS, offering a unified API for video encoding across multiple vendor-specific abstractions, ranging from Intel ([Quicksync](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/quick-sync-video/quick-sync-video-general.html)) and AMD GPUs (Prior generation [VCE](https://github.com/obsproject/obs-amd-encoder/wiki/Hardware-Support#Video_Coding_Engine_10) and current generation [VCN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_Core_Next) SIP blocks) on x86, and including the latest [Apple Silicon's M-series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_silicon#M_series) ARM SoCs.

Grab a build here: https://evermeet.cx/ffmpeg/

Comment: Are args like `-crf` or `-b:v` available in hevc_videotoolbox? Or how to check an arg is common or specific to an encoder? Thanks!

Comment: @amdyes Nope. I am running macOS Mojave (10.15) on a 2019 MacBook Air with the latest install of FFmpeg from Homebrew, and honestly using `hevc_videotoolbox` is quite horrible. Speed is 2x to 3x playback speed of the source video, which is great! But the quality of the output is abysmal to be honest. The only way I got it to show decent (but still not great) quality for 720p video was by using `-profile:v main -b:v 5500k` but the filesize is not much different than the source 1080p video. Might be useful for streaming crappy video but seems like a experimental feature for now.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this has changed since the OP's comment, but in FFmpeg 4.x the command is:

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -h encoder=hevc_videotoolbox
```